# Azure B2C verify Phone number on Sign UP?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am building a custom policy for B2C Sign up.

We currently do not use B2C to do sign ups, but im looking to migrate. Part of this process would require the use of an email and a phone number.

The phone number ONLY would need to be verified.

So after the user signs up for an account an SMS or phone call would verify that they own that phone number.

Looking in the documentation, i see verify phone number, but its for sign up with a phone number. I dont want to do that.

I just want the phone number to verify during the sign up process.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PhoneFactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile) technical profile.

The "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" flow asks for a phone number if not present and verifies or just verifies if present.

Comment: So i have that technical profile in my extensions folder. I call the technical profile in the sign up flow. But there is never a prompt to enter phone number let alone verify it.

Comment: Have a look at this policy - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone

Comment: This is for sign in. I ONLY need the Phone verification on Sign up. Once the number is verified I dont care anymore.

Comment: from @rbrayb's answer you've to define a phonefactor technical profile. See this one https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

Use the default starter pack. Just add a precondition to skip the phonefactor step if newUser claim does not exist. That will trigger MFA prompt only on sign up.